# Jquery - Need a way to stringify a large variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Seems silly but been at this for several hours now. I'm trying to stringify a variable.

This is an example of the variable and it can go as long as 700 lines.

```
var test = "1",
"2",
"3",
"4",
"5",
"6",
"7",
"8",
"9",
"10";
```

What I would like my variable to return is this:

```
 "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"
```

I tried using JSON.stringify but doesn't return with quotes correctly. Curious to know if you guys know of a better method to do this?

Comment: Did you try to run the code, it throws syntax errors.

Comment: How about using an array and then stringifying (when needed) it using JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make an array to store your list then apply JSON.stringify.
Here you can check this

```js
var test = ["1",
"2",
"3",
"4",
"5",
"6",
"7",
"8",
"9",
"10"];
console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
```